# Magnolia, JCR, sort node order by customized property value

Tags: java, sorting, aem, jcr, magnolia

For example, i have a node ref 29949, it has property like this:
[image]

so it's positionIndex is 1,  this is a customized property.
my current nodes is totally unordered, like this:

[image]

I wish to compare and sort node into a ascending order by this property-positionIndex,  so this node 29949 will stand under 44440, as 44440 has value positionIndex 0.  Anyone got any idea how to do that? any code example would be nice.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should grab a session for yourself like (also can be injected)

```
Context context = MgnlContext.getInstance();
Session session = context.getJcrSession("choiceOfWorkspace");

// Must be the parent of the nodes to be compared.

Node rootNode = session.getRootNode();
NodeIterator iterator = rootNode.getNodes();

// just do an iteration over the iterator

while(iterator.hasNext()){
Node nextNode = iterator.nextNode();
property = nextNode.getProperty("positionIndex");
// do any sorting algorithm here
}
```

Hope this helps

Cheers,